# Magento 1.7.0.2 on PHP 5.6 is not loading

Tags: magento-1.7, server, php-5.6

I am trying to upgrade my PHP version to 5.6.1 to get PCI DSS compliance certificate.

We compiled and enabled 5.6.1 on server and used it with an ApplicationHandler in .htaccess file.

On the same server for the subdomain DEV it worked without any problems. PDOs were a bit problematic but we handled to add the correct PDOs to PHP library.

Just some deprecated function usage errors which are easy to fix, but when I try to add it to live version via .htaccess it did not work at all. All I see is a blank page. No error messages, no reports, no logs, nothing. Just a blank page is welcoming me.

I checked all the enabled Extensions, they all are same.

I searched a lot on web to find some similar cases, came out nothing. I am all empty handed on the issue and I need to make it work.

If there is any body who experienced such a problem please let me know.

Comment: 1.7.0.2 is not compatible with PHP 5.6. Is this on some 'cPanel' thing, and why can't you install PHP from a repository?

Comment: Yes sure I know it is not compatible with php 5.6 but that does not mean it can not work with php 5.6 and also as I mentioned in my post it works already in DEV.domain.com but not on www.domain.com.

Comment: In chasing this PCI compliance piece-of-paperwork you have built a server that is not maintainable.

Comment: You are just assuming something which is not true instead of trying to give helpful information! This server is a cloud server running on a pretty strong hardware and software which is maintained by professionals instead of childish people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check your apache error log.  You should make sure it isn't generating errors or you may very well get a blank screen.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. After checking the logs we found out that IonCube was not loaded properly, now it is fixed and everything works fine.