# Is Magento 1.7.0.2. compatible with PHP 5.6

Tags: magento-1.7, php, upgrade, php-5.6

I now have to upgrade PHP from version 5.4.45 to 5.6. and I have 2 magento sites running on it.

What compatibility problems should I expect if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Magento 1.7 does not support PHP 5.6**

It says so on [the official system requirements page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html)

[image]

You can expect a [Blank screen](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60415/magento-1-7-0-2-on-php-5-6-is-not-loading) when you upgrade.

I advise you to test PHP 5.6 on a stage site first before going live.